# wso2am: Giving the end user the ability to revoke access

Tags: oauth, wso2-api-manager, shibboleth, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I'm working on my master where I have to design and prove a solution to expose some university legacy services. None of them have controlled access, so other feature needed is this security layer.
To make this possible I'm using wso2 products: wso2ebs to make some orchestration and messaging transformation; wso2is to connect to a shibboleth idp that already exists; and wso2am to put everything together and expose the services.

I already have the identity provider (Shibboleth) configured on wso2is. I use this http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/12/10/federation-testshib/ to prove it. 
To make the authentication layer, I'm not sure but I think that I can use this http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/03/bring-your-social-identity-to-perform-organizational-authorization-actions-with-wso2-identity-server/ to make the bond between wso2is and wso2am.

But there is a use case I can't solve: wso2am give me an oauth like environment to expose my private services, but how can a student (end user) manage is authorisations? I as a student which use a mobile app that consume information given by an api exposed by wso2am, want to revoke this this authorisations given previously to this mobile app. How can I do this?

TLDR:
If wso2am use an oauth like environment to expose apis, is there a way to the end user revoke an authorisation given previously to an mobile app that make use of an api exposed by wso2apim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options

1. If you have client_id, Secret and access token on your hand you can use https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Token+API revoking access tokens part
2. If not you can use revokeAuthzForAppsByResoureOwner operation in OAuthAdminService

Comment: So to give the end user this ability, I still have to build a user interface, right? Or is there other way?

Comment: for the first option you can just use REST client and for the second one you can use SoapUI or else you have to use service stub with client application